# ERROR! Syntax Error while loading YAML. AWX/Ansible

Tags: syntax, ansible, ansible-awx

I am using AWX and trying to run this task:

```
- name: cleanup
  shell: awk '{ a[$1 OFS] = a[$1 OFS] ( a[$1 OFS] == "" ? "" : OFS) $2 }END{ for (i in a){print i,a[i]} } OFS="\t" latest.txt "{{ inventory_hostname }}".txt > ./output/"{{ inventory_hostname }}".txt
```

But I am getting this Error:

```
> ERROR! Syntax Error while loading YAML.   did not find expected key
> The error appears to be in
> '/tmp/awx_8887_nv3efn13/project/Simsek/test/test.yml': line 141,
> column 60, but may be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact
> syntax problem. The offending line appears to be:
>     - name: cleanup
>       shell: "awk '{ a[$1 OFS] = a[$1 OFS] ( a[$1 OFS] == "" ? "" : OFS) $2 }END{ for (i in a){print i,a[i]} } OFS="\t" latest.txt "{{
> inventory_hostname }}".txt > ./output/"{{ inventory_hostname }}".txt"
>                                                            ^ here We could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with
> missing quotes. Always quote template expression brackets when they
> start a value. For instance:
>     with_items:
>       - {{ foo }} Should be written as:
>     with_items:
>       - "{{ foo }}"
```

Comment: Looks like ansible does not like the : 
I am not able to find a way arround that problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
awk '{ a[$1 OFS] = a[$1 OFS] ( a[$1 OFS] == "" ? "" : OFS) $2 }END{ for (i in a){print i,a[i]} } OFS="\t"' latest.txt {{ inventory_hostname }}.txt > ./output/{{ inventory_hostname }}.txt
```